# What is the most concise way of passing named arguments to a Golang tool and to use them?

Tags: go, arguments, command-line-arguments

**Aim:** to pass named arguments to a Golang tool and to use the passed arguments as variables

---

**Attempt**

Compiling the [following example](https://gobyexample.com/command-line-arguments):

> ```
> package main
>
> import (
>   "fmt"
>   "os"
> )
>
> func main() {
>   argsWithProg := os.Args
>   argsWithoutProg := os.Args[1:]
>   arg := os.Args[3]
>
>   fmt.Println(argsWithProg)
>   fmt.Println(argsWithoutProg)
>   fmt.Println(arg)
> }
> ```

---

build it and pass arguments, e.g.: `./args -a=1 -b=2 -c=3 -d=4 -e=5 -f=6`, results in:

```
[./args -a=1 -b=2 -c=3 -d=4 -e=5 -f=6]
[-a=1 -b=2 -c=3 -d=4 -e=5 -f=6]
-c=3
```

Based on this answer, the following snippet was added to the example:

```
s := strings.Split(arg, "=")
variable, value := s[0], s[1]
fmt.Println(variable, value)
```

and after building it and passing arguments the output is as follows:

```
[./args -a=1 -b=2 -c=3 -d=4 -e=5 -f=6]
[-a=1 -b=2 -c=3 -d=4 -e=5 -f=6]
-c=3
-c 3
```

**Question**

Although the aim has been accomplished I wonder whether this is the most concise way to pass named arguments and to use them in Golang.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [Package flag](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/)
>
> ```
> import "flag"
> ```
>
> Package flag implements command-line flag parsing.

Try the `flag` and other similar packages.